# Keeping the formatting of the cut cells preserved

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with some cells formatted (like borders, background colors).

[image]

User may cut/paste data.

**The problem:** when cutting/pasting, the formatting (borders) is gone.

[image]

How to keep the formatting of the cut cells preserved?

Thanks.

Comment: I would do a copy/paste, then go back and just delete the cell contents of the original (using, for example, the `Del` key).

Comment: I cannot force the user to proceed like that. As you may know, users do what they want without thinking of consequences :)

Comment: This is native Excel functionality, it's not something you can turn on or off. You can write a macro that will perform the same actions as a copy/ paste, then wire it up to the CTRL+X hotkey. This will simulate the "cut/ paste" and preserve formatting. However, there are a number of ways to cut/ paste (i.e. right-click, cut) that won't be considered here.

Comment: I am not aware of any mechanism that can totally prevent users from hurting themselves in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is almost 3 years late, but maybe someone still need an answer.

To avoid losing your format while cutting, you just have to format the original range or column with the "format cells option"

[image: Format Cells Menu]

I hope someone find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  "Cut" means "cut everything including formatting".

Just go with copy, paste and delete. It is the closest option to what you want.

Comment: You are right. So I'll disable any `Cut` inside my XL sheet. This may be useful: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=373

Answer (score 0):

Use “format as table” and create a custom style that has all of the cells outlined.